# What is the difference between a[n+1] and a[n]+1 inside an array?

Tags: arrays

I looked and looked on the website to find the answer to this but I couldnt find it anywhere.

However, what is the difference?

Here is what I think.

Say I have an array with five elements in it, a[5]. a[n+1] would be the second element, a[n+2] would be the third, etc.

a[n]+1 would be, say I type in a number into the first element [n]. Say that number is 27, since a[n]+1 would equal 28.

Comment: you answered your own question `a[i]` gets the i'th element of the array. `a[i] + 1` gets the i'th element and adds one to it.

Comment: @user249240 please try to use the tag system correctly. If you're in doubt, read a bit the descriptions of a tag before deciding if it's relevant to your question.

Comment: Thank you guys. However quick question. Why was this question downvoted? I did my best to present it in the best format I could, I searched around for an answer and I showed you guys the work that I have done and didnt just ask for an answer. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a[n]+ 1 takes value from a[n] and adds 1 to it.

a[n+1] takes value of n and adds 1 to it.

Bothe are completely different in meaning context. a[n+1] is *index increment and value retrieval from specified list and index*. a[n] + 1 is `value retrieval from specified list and index then adding 1 to it.`

For example,

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

n = 2

a[n+1] is a[2+1] => a[3] => 4

a[n] + 1 is a[2] + 1 => 3 + 1 => 4
```

Comment: So does this mean that the way that I explained it in my example, it is correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. One thing you have to remember is whatever the number is in a[n] after a[n]+1 will be one plus whatever number in a[n]